# Convert list to list of ids

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

Python 3.3:

What is the easiest way to obtain from the list:

```
input = ["A", 112, "apple", 74, 112]
```

following list:

```
output = [0, 1, 2, 3, 1]
```

That is, assign automatically incremented id starting from 0 to every unique entry, and convert the original list to the list of this ids.

I am aware, that I can obtain cheap the number of classes by

```
number_of_classes = len(set(input))
```

But how to create correctly ordered output?

Comment: One way would be to use a dictionary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to @ajcr answer, which is fine for small lists, here is solution that has linerar computational complexity (while using `list.index()` has O(n^2)):

```
data = ["A", 112, "apple", 74, 112]
index = {val: i for i, val in reversed(list(enumerate(data)))}
indexes = [index[x] for x in data]
indexed = [(x, index[x]) for x in data]

print index
print indexes
print indexed
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's very elegant.

Answer (score 13):

You could use list comprehension to create a list of indexes of when the element *first* occurs in that list.

For an input list `i = ["A", 112, "apple", 74, 112]`:

```
>>> [i.index(value) for value in i]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 1]
```

Comment: This is neat my friend!

Comment: I was happy to see this solution (y)

Comment: good, simple solution for short lists, but for longer complexity can be problem. +1 anyway

Comment: Thanks all. You're right about complexity - `set`/`dict` answers will be more efficient for longer lists.

Answer (score 1):

Just keep a another list with the keys and use the array.index() method to get the index of the item:

```
input = ["A", 112, "apple", 74, 112]
keys = []
output = []

for item in input:
   if item not in keys:
      keys.append(item)
   output.append(keys.index(item))

print output
```

Answer (score 0):

Using dictionary:

```
input = ["A", 112, "apple", 74, 112]
dictMap = dict((i[1],i[0]) for i in enumerate(set(input)))
print [dictMap[i] for i in input]
```

Output:

```
[0, 1, 3, 2, 1]
```

Comment: Passing `input` to `set` will already lead to arbitrary order, have you looked at your output?

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> input = ["A", 112, "apple", 74, 112]
>>> my_dict = {x:i for i,x in enumerate(sorted(set(input),key=input.index))}  # need to as set dosent remember order
>>> my_dict
{'A': 0, 112: 1, 74: 3, 'apple': 2}
>>> [ my_dict[x] for x in input ]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 1]
```